# Cast string to enum

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I have a method in C# that calls a stored procedure and fills out a `DataTable` with values. I have problem in a line that the return value from my stored procedure is a string whereas the property that I am using to keep the value in my C# comes from a class that the type is an enum. I try to cast but I keep getting this error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

This is my method to call the stored procedure:

```
public void GetOrder()
{
    ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["T_DB"];
    string conString = connectionString.ConnectionString;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LH_Get_order", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onum", 45642);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.BatchId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gbo_batch_id"].ToString();
            this.ExternalRefId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["o_num"].ToString();
            this.LoanId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["o_loan"].ToString();
            this.OrderType = (eOrderType)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OrderType"]; //problem
        }
    }
}
```

Problem occurs on this line:

```
this.OrderType = (eOrderType)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OrderType"];
```

This is my `OrderType` property:

```
public eOrderType OrderType
{
    get { return _OrderType; }
    set { _OrderType = value; }
}
```

and this is `eOrderType` enum:

```
public enum eOrderType : int {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute(Value="CVA BPO")]
    CVABPO = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    ExteriorBPO = 2,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Inspection = 3,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    RepairEstimate = 4,
}
```

Comment: So presumably the data is stored as a string in the database, right? You might just want Enum.Parse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(eOrderType) Enum.Parse(typeof(eOrderType ),ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OrderType"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string to an enum value instead of casting:

```
eOrderType orderType;
if(Enum.TryParse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OrderType"], out orderType))
{
    this.OrderType = orderType;
}
else
{
    //parse failed
}
```